# Comparing WP dates

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, date

I´m trying to show posts with a meta field "fecha_inicio" that contains a younger date with this format "dd/mm/yyyy" with 1 variable that also has a date with the same format "dd/mm/yyyy". 
My code is the next one:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 30,
    'post_type' => 'programa',
    'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'   =>  'fecha_inicio',
            'value' =>  $fecha,
            'type'  => 'date',
            'compare'=> '<'
        ),
    ),
);
```

This doesn´t return me anything. I have posts for example with date 10/10/2016 and 01/01/2016, and I´m trying the query with a date in the middle 05/05/2016, and It´s not returning me anything

I have printed the variable and shows the correct date, and also the other dates are correct on the database, dunno what I am missing here.

---

Also the field has the same name, that in the table post_meta

---

Trying to show the SQL Query

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
  wp_posts.ID
FROM
  wp_posts
INNER JOIN
  wp_postmeta
ON
  (
    wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
  )
WHERE
  1 = 1 AND(
    (
      wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'fecha_inicio' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS DATE) > '01/05/2095'
    )
  ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'programa' AND(
    wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private'
  )
GROUP BY
  wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY
  wp_posts.post_date
DESC
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: try print_r($wp_query->request) and see if query is right @ivannaxara

Comment: @parthmahida I´m not very good in SQL sentences, but I guess it´s correct, I have edited the Question with the SQL Sentence

Comment: try running this query in your phpmyadmin or whatever you use for sql, and look for errors or try to modify the date format @ivannaxara

Comment: @parthmahida I just did it, It doesn´t give any error, just returns 0 rows

Comment: the date in your query is '01/05/2095', you have data greater then this date? @ivannaxara

Comment: @parthmahida Yes, I have one on 2100 and others on 2016

Comment: Even if you work with your dates in dd/mm/yyyy, MySQL stores them in yyyy-mm-dd. I'd try this format in both your SQL and PHP.